# Exit Plink when command finishes

Tags: linux, shell, batch-file, putty, plink

I'm trying run multiple command lines via `plink.exe`. After batch is finished. I want to exit this and execute new command line

My script in `execute.bat` file

```
(
echo cd /appl/
echo sudo -s
echo cd apache-tomcat/webapps/Test
echo sh ./J50X100.sh
) | plink.exe -batch host -l user -pw pass
```

Actual: It's still in remote, I cannot execute new command line

[image: Actual details here]

Expected: Exit this and is able to execute new command line

Comment: may be this link helps you https://stackoverflow.com/a/33568044/1594178

Answer (score 2):

The way you are using Plink, it opens an interactive shell session. As with every interactive shell session, it has to be exited with `exit` command. In you case, with two `exit` commands actually, first to exit `sudo`, then to exit the login shell.

---

Though you better avoid using the interactive shell altogether by specifying the command on Plink command line:

```
plink.exe -batch host -l user -pw pass "cd /appl/ ; sudo -s 'cd apache-tomcat/webapps/Test ; sh ./J50X100.sh '"
```

Though this approach might be problematic with your specific case, as you will have to configure `sudo` to allow this command – But you should do it, as it is the right approach. You have to edit [`sudoers` file](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/sudoers.5.html) – Ideally, you should create a script that does `cd apache-tomcat/webapps/Test ; sh ./J50X100.sh` and allow that script in `sudoers`.